# can we inject flex/air based component in winform application?

Tags: winforms, apache-flex

I am starting to write a flex based data visualization application. I would like to consider the possibility of injecting this as a component in an existing MDI winforms application.

Is there a way to server this integration by deploying my flex app as a AIR based application and somehow integrate it in a MDI winform application as a child window ?

I highly doubt this is possible but would like to know if someone made an attempt to do this sort of integration successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you can integrate a IE instance in WinForm then you should be able to run the flex from there.

Communication could then be established between winform and flex via ExternalInterface in Flex (which talks to javascript in the IE instance).

Comment: That's a good option. In this case will the flex part be running as a separate process or under winform process ?

Comment: I'm not sure... I would say winform's.